# How can I make Graphics objects clickable?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, gui-construction, interactive

I have created a list (`listA`) that specifies disks based on color, center point, and radius:

```
(* Define disks based on (i) color, (ii) center point, and (iii)
radius. listA is a list of such disks. *)
listA = {
   {Red, {0, 0}, 0.5},(* object 1 *)
   {Blue, {1, 1}, 0.75}(* object 2 *)
   };
```

I have also defined a function `displayList` to display the disks with `Graphics`:

```
(* Create a function to plot the disks using Graphics. *)
displayList[list_List] := Module[{},
   Graphics[{
     list[[1, 1]], Apply[Disk, list[[1, 2 ;; 3]]],
     list[[2, 1]], Apply[Disk, list[[2, 2 ;; 3]]]
     }
    , Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
   ];
```

Applying `displayList` to `listA` gives graphical output:

```
displayList[listA]
```

> [image: disks]

**I would like to make the disks "clickable"** -- I would like the disks' color to (dynamically) change when the user clicks on the disks.

Specifically, I want the following:

- When the user clicks on the red disk (i.e., the disk of radius 0.5 centered at `{0, 0}`), `listA` is updated so that `listA[[1, 1]]` changes from `Red` to `Blue`; and `displayList[listA]` is automatically reevaluated so that the disk is now displayed as blue.
- When the user clicks on the blue disk (i.e., the disk of radius 0.75 centered at `{1, 1}`), `listA` is updated so that `listA[[2, 1]]` changes from `Blue` to `Red`; and `displayList[listA]` is automatically reevaluated so that  the disk is now displayed as red.

***How should I go about approaching this problem?***  Should I think about defining a Locator for each disk?

Comment: Take a look at `ClickPane`, `Button`, `EventHandler` and `Dynamic` in general.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of ways to do what you ask for. I decided that an implementation based on `FlipView` and `Insert` would be fun because I had not used that approach before. Also, I decided to use an association to hold the disk parameters because I believe doing so makes the code more readable.

```
diskData =
  {<|"cntr" -> {0, 0}, "r" -> .5, "hues" -> {Red , Blue}|>,
   <|"cntr" -> {1, 1}, "r" -> .75, "hues" -> {Blue, Red}|>};

flipper[disk_Association] :=
  Inset[
    FlipView[Graphics[{#, Disk[]}] & /@ disk["hues"]], 
    disk["cntr"], Automatic, 2 disk["r"]]

Graphics[flipper /@ diskData, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2]
```

[image: graphics]

Clicking on either the two disks will change that disk's color.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Graphics within Graphics is that the inner one won't respect things like `AspectRatio` or coordinate system in general.

Here is how I would do it, with `Dynamic @ color` nothing but color needs to be reevaluated. For more complicated cases it is crucial not to rerender the whole graphics again and again and not to transfer redundant data between kernel and frontend.

```
Graphics[
  Table[ 
    With[{i = i},
      EventHandler[
        { Dynamic @ listA[[i, 1]], Disk @@ listA[[i, 2 ;;]]}
      , "MouseClicked" :> (listA[[i, 1]] = listA[[i, 1]] /. {Red -> Blue, Blue -> Red})
      ]
    ]
  , {i, Length @ listA}
  ]
, Frame -> True
, PlotRange -> 2
, AspectRatio -> 1/2
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like goldberg's idea of using `Inset`. Here is an extension which includes a readback of the current state:

```
diskData = {
   <|"cntr" -> {0, 0}, "r" -> .5, "hues" -> {Red, Blue}, 
    "currentValue" -> Unique[currentValue]|>,
   <|"cntr" -> {1, 1}, "r" -> .75, "hues" -> {Blue, Red}, 
    "currentValue" -> Unique[currentValue]|>};

flipper[disk_Association] := Inset[
   FlipView[
     Graphics[{#, Disk[]}] & /@ disk["hues"], 
     With[{currentval = disk["currentValue"]}, Dynamic[currentval]]
   ],
   disk["cntr"], Automatic, 2 disk["r"]];

Column@{
   Graphics[flipper /@ diskData, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2, ImageSize -> Medium],
   Dynamic@diskData[[All, "currentValue"]]
}
```

It uses a second argument to `FlipView`:

> FlipView[list,Dynamic[i]] takes the displayed object to be specified
>   by the dynamically updated current value of i, with the value of i
>   being reset if a new object is displayed.

A unique symbol is created for each disk in `diskData` that will hold the current state of the disk in FlipView. `With` is used to inject the symbol into the `Dynamic` statement.

One possible issue is that new unique symbols are created for each evaluation of `diskData`, and that there is no garbage collection for symbols which are no longer used.